# Is there a nice way to invert this expression?

Tags: modular-forms, special-functions, generating-functions, symmetric-functions

Let us first define the Euler polynomials to be the polynomials $P_n(q)$ that satisfy
$$
\frac{qP_n(q)}{(1 - q)^{n+1}} = \Big(q\frac{d}{dq}\Big)^n\frac{q}{1 - q}.
$$

For example, $P_0(q) = P_1(q) = 1$, and $P_2(q) = 1 + q$. One should note that these polynomials are always palindromic, and of degree $n - 1$, and satisfy a pretty easy-to-determine recursion from the above definition.

Next, let us consider the following expression.
$$
T_n(q, x) = (1 - q)^{2n + 2} - x^2 q P_{2n+1}(q)
$$
For $n = 0$, this is simply
$$
(1 - q)^2 - x^2q = 1 - (x^2 + 2)q + q^2.
$$
We note that this polynomial is also palindromic (as $(1 - q)^{2n + 2}$ is), and so we can factor it as
$$
T_n(q, x) = \prod_{j=0}^n(1 - \zeta_j q)(1 - \zeta_j^{-1} q)
$$
for some expressions $\zeta_j$.

The goal is now to write $x$ as a function of these $\zeta_j$. For example, if $n = 0$, then we have
$$
1 - (x^2 + 2)q + q^2 = (1 - \zeta q)(1 - \zeta^{-1} q)
$$
or
$$
x^2 = \zeta + \zeta^{-1} - 2 \iff x = \zeta^{1/2} - \zeta^{-1/2}
$$
which is a nice and simple expression.

For higher $n$, let us define $\mu_j = \zeta_j^{1/2} - \zeta_j^{-1/2}$, and so $\mu_j^2 = \zeta_j + \zeta_j^{-1} - 2$. Then, for example, for $n = 1$ we have that
$$
\begin{align}
x^2 &= \mu_1^2 + \mu_2^2 \\
-6x^2 &= \mu_1^2\mu_2^2
\end{align}
$$
and in general what we find is that for each $n$, that we have a series of expressions
$$
c_{n, k} x^2 = \sigma_k(\mu_1^2, \ldots, \mu_n^2)
$$
where $c_{n, k}$ are some integral coefficients (related to [A036969](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C21%2C14%2C1&sort=&language=english&go=Search)) and $\sigma_k$ is the $k$-the elementary symmetric polynomial. These expressions should allow us to derive relations among the $\zeta_j$s, but it doesn't seem clear to me how these should look; in particular, for $n = 1$ the best that I can find is that
$$
x = \frac{\mu_1^2}{\sqrt{6 + \mu_1^2}} = \frac{\zeta_1 + \zeta_1^{-1} - 2}{\sqrt{4 + \zeta_1 + \zeta_1^{-1}}}
$$
which isn't really as nice as the expression $x = \zeta^{1/2} - \zeta^{-1/2}$.

As for motivation (e.g. why $x^2$?), what I'm working with is an expression of the form
$$
\sum_n A_n(q)x^{2n} = \prod_m T_k(q^m,x)
$$
and the right-side of this expression is manifestly (quasi-)modular; what I'd like to understand is what that means for the left-hand side.